# Query usernames out or parse array, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an array stored in Parse called friends and friends has usernames in it, I need to query each username and get information from the users and store that information in different Arrays, this is what I have right now. It works but its really slow because for some reason it queries 7 times. Thanks in advance!

```
    var friends: [AnyObject] = user["friends"] as Array
    var bioArray = [""]
    var statusArray = [""]
    var pictureArray = [] as NSMutableArray
    var pictureUrl = [""]
    for(var i = 0; i < friends.count; i++){
        var query = PFUser.query()
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo:friends[i])
        var friendsArray = query.findObjects()
        var bios : AnyObject = friendsArray[0]["bio"] as String
        var status : AnyObject = friendsArray[0]["status"] as NSObject
        var profilePicture: AnyObject = friendsArray[0]["profilePicture"] as PFFile
        bioArray.insert("\(bios)", atIndex: bioArray.count-1)
        statusArray.insert("\(status)", atIndex: statusArray.count-1)
        pictureArray.addObject(profilePicture)
        pictureUrl.insert(pictureArray[0].url, atIndex: pictureUrl.count-1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you create a new query everytime you loop trough your array..

Try it like this

```
var friends: [AnyObject] = user["friends"] as Array

var bioArray = [""]
var statusArray = [""]
var pictureArray = [] as NSMutableArray
var pictureUrl = [""]

for var object in friends {
    if friend is objects as? PFUser() {
    var bios = friend["bio"]
    // add it to the array etc
    }
}
```

If you dont get all the user info you can call the function fetchIfNeeded

```
friend.fetchIfNeeded()
```